# Material UI Autocomplete: exclude defaults from options

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a Material-ui autocomplete element (tags mode) with a list of options and a list of defaults, which are also included in the options. Is there a way to exclude the defualts from being able to be added a second time?

I've tried using

```js
for (var i = options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < defualtOptions.length; j++) {
        if (options[i] && options[i].name === defualtOptions[j].name) {
            options.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

but this means that if any of the deafult options are removed, they won't show up to be re-selected.

Here's my code for the component:

```js
export default function PersonPicker(params) {
    let { people, defualtPeople, label, variant, onChange } = params;

    for (var i = people.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var j = 0; j < defualtPeople.length; j++) {
            if (people[i] && people[i].name === defualtPeople[j].name) {
                people.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Autocomplete
                onChange={(event, value) => onChange(event, value)}
                multiple={true}
                options={people}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                defaultValue={defualtPeople}
                filterSelectedOptions={true}
                selectOnFocus={true}
                renderInput={(paramaters) => (
                    <TextField
                        variant={variant}
                        label={label}
                        placeholder={label}
                        {...paramaters}
                        {...params}
                    />
                )}
                renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) => {
                    return tagValue.map((option, index) => (
                        <Chip
                            {...getTagProps({ index })}
                            label={option.name}
                            avatar={
                                <Avatar
                                    alt={option.name}
                                    src={option.imageSrc}
                                />
                            }
                        />
                    ));
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I would recommend adding the piece of code of the component:
Something like <Autocomplete  options={options} defaultValue={defaultOptions} />

Comment: Of course, that was silly of me to forget!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the question, but, unless I'm wrong, what you need is achievable by simply using the `filterSelectedOptions` prop in the autocomplete component. If it doesn't work, maybe you should check what's the option value/prop used for comparison, that makes your component not filter as it's supposed to. I think the problem is more about what's using as comparison, than any other thing.

Using your question code as example:

```
<Autocomplete
            onChange={(event, value) => onChange(event, value)}
            multiple={true}
            options={people}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
            defaultValue={defualtPeople}
            filterSelectedOptions
            selectOnFocus={true}
            renderInput={(paramaters) => (
                <TextField
                    variant={variant}
                    label={label}
                    placeholder={label}
                    {...paramaters}
                    {...params}
                />
            )}
```

Take a look at the docs:
https://material-ui.com/es/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values

Comment: Thanks! Based off of your suggestion I found [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-b3nsz?file=/demo.js) which showed me how to make it work.